# Necesito orientacion para crear una variable de sesion, estoy utilizando codeigniter y ajax

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter-3, session

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model("consultas");
        $this->load->helper("url");

  }

    public function index()
    {

            $this->load->view("login");
    }

    public function ingresar()
    {

        extract($_POST); 

        $datos=$this->consultas->traer_datos($u, $p);
        if($datos != null){ 

            echo json_encode(array("status" => "true","datos" => array($datos),"mensaje" => "Datos Correctos.")); 
        }else{
            echo json_encode (array("status" => "false","mensaje" => "Datos Incorrectos.")); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo crear una variable de sesión.

Si trabajas con **codeigniter** lo primero que debes asegurar en tu proyecto en la ruta: ***application/config/autoload.php***  , que la siguiente línea este así: **$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');** ,esto con intención clara de usar sesiones en codeigniter.

Posteriormente lo que hago yo es: 
Primero capturo mi dato por POST  y luego lo asigno a una variable de sesión

```html
//Recogemos el identificador por POST
$Mmatricula = $this->input->post('matricula'); 

//Lo asignamos a una variable de sesión   
$this->session->set_userdata('matricula',$Mmatricula);

//Usamos la sesión guardada asignándola a una variable. 
$valmatricula = $this->session->userdata('matricula');
```